# Change of printed values inside #ifdefs, C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to use `#ifdef` for debugging in order to reduce the amount of `printf`s active in my code, but the values printed inside the `#ifdef` is different from the value printed outside.

```
    printf("Number of bytes: %d\n", size);
    can_message* message;
    message->datalength = size;
    message->id = id;
    for (int i; i < size; i++)
    {
        message->data[i] = data[i]; 
    }
    #ifdef CAN_MESSAGE_INIT_DEBUG
    printf("Number of bytes: %d\n", size);
    printf("Message created, ID: %d, datalength: %d, ",message->id, message->datalength);
    for (int i; i < message->datalength; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", message->data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    #endif
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Number of bytes: 3
Number of bytes: +2422235261Q
```

I'm currently programming an Atmega162 in Atmel Studio. No interrupts trigger during this printing, so what is the issue?

Comment: What type is `size`? If it is `size_t` then you need `printf("Number of bytes: %zu\n", size);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing into unallocated memory.  Look at this code:

```
can_message* message;
message->datalength = size;
message->id = id;
```

You create a pointer to `message` but never allocate memory for it.  Then you dereference the memory (`->`) and write values into it.  This potentially trashes the memory location where `size` resides.

Comment: Changing the pointer solved the issue! Seems like allocation was the only issue here